# Unable to access data from object created using json file

Tags: json, object

i am trying to access data from x which is created using the json file i am unable to acces the data it shows undefined but i can see the object in console

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x ={};
      $.getJSON("countries.json", function(json) {
          for (i in json['results'])
          {
              x[json['results'][i]['currencyId']] = json['results'][i]['name'];
          }
    });
    console.log(x);
    //console.log(x.AED); cannot access values using property names output is undefined
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: getJSON is async, so you're probably trying to log the value before property was even set on that object.

Answer (score 0):

As Ibsn said in the comment you are checking the value before it was assigned.

You should log the result inside the callback function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x ={};
  $.getJSON("countries.json", function(json) {
      for (i in json['results'])
      {
          x[json['results'][i]['currencyId']] = json['results'][i]['name'];
      }
      console.log(x);
});
```